# StickyJS: how to change css when element is "sticky"?

Tags: javascript

I'm using http://stickyjs.com/ to fix a social share bar at the top of my website.

I got it to work as intended embedding this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sticker").sticky({topSpacing:0})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.sticky/1.0.3/jquery.sticky.min.js"></script>
<div id="sticker">Sticky</div>
```

But now I need to change the share bar color when said bar is "sticky": when element is not sticky, it should be #333, and when it's fixed, it should be #FFF.

I tried changing the css for #sticker(which is the ID for element to be sticky), and it obviously changed the color for both sticky and non-sticky.

Then I saw on this on the github page for the script:

className: (default: 'is-sticky') CSS class added to the element's wrapper when "sticked".

Looks like what I need here, but I can't manage to use it.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

Like it add the class `is-sticky` to your existing class you have to use the css keyword `!important` to overide the background you already define :

```
.is-sticky {
   background-color:#FFF !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that, and it doesn't work. So this is how it's supposed to work indeed ? If yes, then I may have messed something up elsewhere in the website.

Comment: yes normally it's should work. what do you mean by doesn't work ? your background still equal to #333 or do you have another issue ?

Comment: well, maybe I wasn't 100% clear: current background for the social share bar is #333, before it gets fixed. Whith the css in your answer, it gets white before getting fixed, and it stays like that when it gets sticky. What I need is for it to go from  #333 to #FFF when it gets sticky.

Comment: ok by adding the code above your element's background is white in all cases? if yes could you verify by inspecting the element if the class is-sticky is apply in all cases

Comment: yes, white in all cases. Plus, is-sticky is applied both in "regular" case, as well when position:fixed.

Comment: ok i check in the doc http://stickyjs.com/ the class `is-sticky` is not apply if the element is not sticked. Do you add the class in your html ? have you got another css class that define white background ? in all cases could you share in a codepen or a plunkr the part of your project that doesn't run ?